# post the ajax data in mysql

Tags: php, javascript, html, mysql, ajax

I have an ajax code that automatically  send the information of an html form to mysql without clicking submit.  In mysql, I see that the script send no information.  Blank data.  I see that the script connection with mysql is good because I see a new result but the result is empty(no text or value)
Here is my ajax code and my php code:

Comment: [**Please, don't use `mysql_*` functions in new code**](http://bit.ly/phpmsql). They are no longer maintained [and are officially deprecated](http://j.mp/XqV7Lp). See the [**red box**](http://j.mp/Te9zIL)? Learn about [*prepared statements*](http://j.mp/T9hLWi) instead, and use [PDO](http://php.net/pdo) or [MySQLi](http://php.net/mysqli) - [this article](http://j.mp/QEx8IB) will help you decide which.

Comment: You sould check if `$_POST['Megalink']` is set, using `isset` function

Comment: You should properly encode your data. eg `encodeURIComponent(Megalink )`

Answer (score 1):

Your data string doesn't comply with your post variables.

```
var data = "newQuickMEGA=" + Megalink +  "&nameQuickMEGA=" + Filename +  "&sizeQuickMEGA=" + Filesize +  "&filecat=" + Filecate;

$link = $_POST['Megalink'];
$name = $_POST['Filename'];
$size = $_POST['Filesize'];
$cat = $_POST['Filecate'];
```

The following would work:

```
$link = $_POST['newQuickMEGA'];
$name = $_POST['nameQuickMEGA'];
$size = $_POST['sizeQuickMEGA'];
$cat = $_POST['filecat'];
```

Comment: Thank you very much!! The script works perfectly!  for the past week, I was looking for a way to do it and now you helped me! Thank you so much!!